# *ngIf not affecting type check in [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I have the following type:

```ts
interface Video {
  metaData?: {
    tags?: {
      TIT2: string;
    };
  };
}
```

In my template

```ts
<form class="meta meta__tags" *ngIf="video.metaData?.tags">
  <input
    [(ngModel)]="video.metaData.tags.TIT2"
    class="title"
    name="tags"
  />
</form>
```

below `tags` I get the error

```ts
Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.ngtsc(2533)
```

Setting

```ts
[(ngModel)]="video.metaData!.tags.TIT2"
```

I get

```ts
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ngtsc(2532)
```

below `TIT2`. It's only working if I set

```ts
[(ngModel)]="video.metaData!.tags!.TIT2"
```

But why is this necessary? `*ngIf="video.metaData?.tags"` should already guarantee that `video.metaData.tags` is not nullish and thus of the form

```ts
{
  TIT2: string
}
```

I could also set

```ts
[(ngModel)]="video.metaData?.tags?.TIT2"
```

but this gives another error:

```ts
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 29 
in [video.metaData?.tags?.TIT2 =$event] in d:/ng/ytd/src/app/components/video/video.component.html@26:21ngtsc(-995002)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a property

```ts
protected tags?: ID3Tags;
```

to my component and then writing

```ts
<form class="meta meta__tags" *ngIf="tags">
  <input [(ngModel)]="tags.TIT2" class="title" name="title" />
</form>
```

solved the problem, although I still think this should not be necessary.